# Renault kangoo 1.4 2006 has no power

Tags: power, renault, clio

My vehicle has no power.. she will drive and reach normal driving speeds for both town driving or open road..however when i need to gear down to overtake or when i need power, she falters and starts to hold back..the car drives like a 850cc mini..absolutely no power whatsoever.

Comment: Have you done any work to it lately? How many miles are on your odometer?

Comment: Is this a general observation or something that's happened recently?  I've driven a Kangoo and felt the same way about it although nothing was actually wrong with it.  If it's something that's started recently, does it relate to anything such as work being done or particular weather conditions.  If it's just started recently and doesn't relate to anything, it may be a sign that the vehicle is ready for a service.

Comment: unfortunately she has been like this since i bought her about 5 years ago... i have changed the fuel pump (3 time) spark plugs, coil, removed the cat box stuffings, heat sensor, timing pickup..throttle body..still same fault..now she is battling to start